# Updating project parameters in AtTask using restsharp put method

Tags: c#, put, restsharp, attask

I am struggling a little in my project with Attask.
My aim is to update the alignmentValues of a project using custom form data..
I have been able to create new alignment values to update but I am unable to execute it using put method...
the request I want to execute is

```
PUT /attask/api/project/4c7...?updates= 
{
    alignmentValues: [ 
        { 
            scoreCardOptionID: "2222...54d0", 
            scoreCardQuestionID : "8897...54d1",... 
        },....
                     ] 
}
```

my code snippet is

```
var request = new RestRequest("project/{id}", Method.PUT);
request.AddUrlSegment("id", pid);
request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
JObject _putData = new JObject();
_putData.Add("alignmentValues",newAnswers);
```

and for updates object I tried few combinations

```
request.AddParameter("updates",_putData,ParameterType.RequestBody); //no effect
request.AddBody(new {name = "updates", value = _putData}); //no effect
```

With this body approach I am even unable to update the name of project.
But when I supply the parameters as query string, it successfully updates the name but fails for alignment values as the url becomes too large

```
var request = new RestRequest("project/{id}?updates=" + _putData , Method.PUT);
```

Above works if _putData is small...like name = "TEST"..but fails for big json array..

Any suggestions on how to update values using addbody/addobject/addjsonobject/addparameter...because I need to send request in body because of its large size...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also used fiddler to look at the request...the request works if the parameters are passed as querystring...but if the same parameters in same format are sent via body, then nothing is happening...
Anyone facing or faced similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

Well this is not an answer but I made it to work by fluke..
SO the main problem still remains..I can't use body with PUT request..Even if I use its shows no result..so I had to go with query string only...
Now for my problem on big parameters in the query string, I was sending the whole alignmentvalues object where I had to update only two fields within that object.
So in a trial and error approach i only passed three fields within the object - answer ID and two fields to be updated...And it reduced the query string size and fortunately for me it worked..